# Split string which contains escaped delimiters

Tags: java, parsing, escaping, delimiter

delimiter is |

escaping character is \

and string is for example `"A|B\|C\\|D\\\|E|\\\\F"`

I want to get array:
`{"A", "B|C\", "D\|E", "\\F"}`

So delimiter can be escaped but escaping character can be also escaped. Does somebody know how to parse this in Java ?

Thanks.

**Edit:**
I created this terribly looking solution. At least It works perfectly and It is possible to define escaping character, delimiter and if empty string should be removed easily.

**SOLUTION (Eggyal posted better one, look down):**

```
private List<String> parseString(String string, String delimiter, boolean removeEmpty) {
    String escapingChar = "\\";
    String escapingCharInRegexp = "\\\\";
    boolean begined = false;
    List<String> parsed = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Integer> begins = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> ends = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> delimitersPositions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<String> explodedParts = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        if( ( string.substring(i, i+1).equals(escapingChar) || string.substring(i, i+1).equals(delimiter) ) && !begined ) {
            begins.add(i);
            begined = true;
            if( i + 1 == string.length() ) {
                begined = false;
                ends.add(i+1);
            }
        } else if( ( !string.substring(i, i+1).equals(escapingChar) && !string.substring(i, i+1).equals(delimiter) && begined ) ) {
            begined = false;
            ends.add(i);
        } else if( begined && string.substring(begins.get(begins.size()-1), i).indexOf(delimiter) != -1 ) {
            begined = false;
            ends.add(i);
            begined = true;
            begins.add(i);
        } 
        if( ( i + 1 == string.length() && begined ) ) {
            begined = false;
            ends.add(i+1);
        }
    }
    List<Integer> toRemove = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for( i = 0; i < begins.size(); i++ ) {
        if( string.substring(begins.get(i), ends.get(i)).indexOf(delimiter) == -1 ) {
            toRemove.add(i);
        }
    }
    for( i = 0; i < toRemove.size(); i++ ) {
        begins.remove(toRemove.get(i)-i);
        ends.remove(toRemove.get(i)-i);
    }       
    for( i = 0; i < begins.size(); i++ ) {
        if( ( ends.get(i) - begins.get(i) ) % 2 != 0 ) {
            delimitersPositions.add(ends.get(i)-1);
        }
    }       
    for( i = 0; i <= delimitersPositions.size(); i++ ) {
        int start = (i == 0) ? 0 : delimitersPositions.get(i-1)+1;
        int end = ( i != delimitersPositions.size()) ? delimitersPositions.get(i) : string.length();
        if( removeEmpty ) {
            if( !string.substring(start, end).equals("") ) {
                explodedParts.add(string.substring(start, end));
            }
        } else {
            explodedParts.add(string.substring(start, end));

        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < explodedParts.size(); i++)
        parsed.add(explodedParts.get(i).replaceAll(escapingCharInRegexp+"(.)", "$1"));

    return parsed;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static final char ESCAPING_CHAR = '\\';

private List<String> parseString(final String  str,
                                 final char    delimiter,
                                 final boolean removeEmpty)
  throws IOException
{
  final Reader        input  = new StringReader(str);
  final StringBuilder part   = new StringBuilder();
  final List<String>  result = new ArrayList<String>();

  int c;
  do {
    c = input.read();                // get the next character

    if (c != delimiter) {            // so long as it isn't a delimiter...
      if (c == ESCAPING_CHAR)        //   if it's an escape
        c = input.read();            //     use the following character instead

      if (c >= 0) {                  //   only if NOT at end of string...
        part.append((char) c);       //     append to current part
        continue;                    //     move on to next character
      }
    }

    /* we're at either a real delimiter, or end of string => part complete */

    if (part.length() > 0 || !removeEmpty) { // keep this part?
      result.add(part.toString());   // add current part to result
      part.setLength(0);             // reset for next part
    }
  } while (c >= 0);                  // repeat until end of string found

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but for example A|\| returns [A]. I would expect [A, |] because second delimiter is escaped so it is normal char.

Comment: @1daemon1: My bad.  It wasn't adding the final part to the result irrespective of its content.  See my revised answer.

Comment: Absolutely great. This one works perfectly and looks nice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks also for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are both splitting *and* unescaping, you need a separate step for each process:

```
String[] terms = input.split("(?<=[^\\\\]|[^\\\\]\\\\\\\\)\\|");
for (int i = 0; i < terms.length; i++)
    terms[i] = terms[i].replaceAll("\\\\(.)", "$1");
```

---

Here's some test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "A|B\\|C\\\\|D\\\\\\|E|\\\\\\\\F";
    String[] terms = input.split("(?<=[^\\\\]|[^\\\\]\\\\\\\\)\\|");
    for (int i = 0; i < terms.length; i++)
        terms[i] = terms[i].replaceAll("\\\\(.)", "$1");
    System.out.println(input);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(terms));
}
```

Output:

```
A|B\|C\\|D\\\|E|\\\\F
[A, B|C\, D\|E, \\F]
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting solution. But for example this input "\\\\|\\\\\\\\|\\\\\\\\\\\\" returns [\|\\|\\\] I would expect [\, \\, \\\]

Comment: I added solution into my post.

Answer (score -1):

There is no escape sequence in java like you've mentioned "\|".
It'll cause compile time error.

Comment: My string is already written as It see compiler. The above example looks like this in Java code: String example = "A|B\\|C\\\\|D\\\\\\|E|\\\\\\\\F"; . The escaping which I need is only some "rule" how to parse between array and string.